# How to get ethereum gasPrice from a transaction hash?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, testing, pending-transactions

I need to get the gasUsed and gasPrice so that I can calculate the correct amount of gas required for a transaction.

I can get the gasUsed using:

```
var accountOneReceipt = await contractInstance.functionName(parameterOne, {from: accountOne});

var accountOneGasUsed = accountOneReceipt.receipt.gasUsed;
```

But there is no gasPrice parameter in transaction receipt.

Info: [getTransactionReceipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=transaction#gettransactionreceipt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `getTransactionReceipt`, I used `getTransaction`

So, to solve the above, we can use:

```
var accountOneGasPrice = (await web3.eth.getTransaction(accountOneReceipt.tx)).gasPrice
```

Where `accountOneReceipt` is the return value we receive from the above function call. And `accountOneReceipt.tx` to get the transaction hash.

Note: `await` is necessary for this code, as else you might get a pending state of the return value, which won't include the `gasPrice`.

Info: [getTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction)